# Navbar won't follow user

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to make the horizontal nav bar stick to the screen once the user scrolls down. However, the nav bar just doesn't stick.

```
        <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse container affix-bottom" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:left">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="logo-transparent.gif" style="height: 4em; margin-top: -1em;"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="logo-name.png" style="width: auto; height: 3em; margin-top: -1em;"/></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right;">
          <li><button id="apply-button-nav" class="nav-button each-button">Apply</button></li>
          <li><button id="about-button-nav" class="nav-button each-button">About</button></li>
          <li><button id="sponsor-button-nav" class="nav-button each-button">Sponsor</button></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the style use `position:fixed`. This fixes the position.

Per W3Schools:

> The element is positioned relative to the browser window

This means it will stay fixed on the screen relative to the window. You can read more about the `position` style attribute here:

[Mozilla Developer Docs - Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your css:

```
.affix {
    position: fixed;
}
```

---

Also, for fixing it without the use of affix, you do not need to add `position: fixed` manually as there is a default class provided by bootstrap for that. Just add class `navbar-fixed-top` to your nav like this:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top container">
```

---

**Note:** If you want it fixed to the bottom, use this class instead: `navbar-fixed-bottom`.